# Background of circles pattern

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I know how easy it is to make a dotted background pattern.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #eee 30px, transparent 1%) center, 
    linear-gradient(#eee 30px, transparent 1%) center, #444;
  background-size: 34px 34px;
}
```

Please, tell me How easy to get circles instead of squares?

```
■ ■ ■   ● ● ●
■ ■ ■ → ● ● ●
■ ■ ■   ● ● ●
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) then control the `background-size` and/or the % of the color stop to achieve the needed pattern:

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000 20%, transparent 22%),#eee; 
  background-size: 34px 34px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000 10%, transparent 12%),#eee; 
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

---

You can also create a circle with SVG and use it with background.

```css
body {
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="#000" /></svg>'); 
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

SVG can be a more generic solution if you need to consider more complex shapes:

```css
body {
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg height="200" width="200"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ><polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" fill="#000" /></svg>'); 
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: Here's a nicer size :) `radial-gradient(circle at center, #000 5%, transparent 10%), #eee;`

Comment: @SirExotic yes but it's more about the trick than the sizing ;) we can easly adjust values later

Comment: Just wanted to help :)